# How to sort category by its creation date in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Any idea how to sort category by its creation date in word press.

Answer (score 5):

actually I'm not sure if category has a creation date but if you order by id, you should get the same result.

```
get_categories(array('orderby'=>'id','order'=>'ASC'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, a term or taxonomy's creation date wasn't stored anywhere in the WP schema. That information is only available for posts... And even then, you only have the modified_date:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` text NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `wp_terms` (
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `term_group` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_taxonomy_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `term_id_taxonomy` (`term_id`,`taxonomy`),
  KEY `taxonomy` (`taxonomy`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your response. But, sometimes id fails to sort :-(

Comment: Try ordering it by `term_taxonomy_id`. It's a reasonably good proxy. (Though, I'm not sure it's actually possible.)